# Haskell openGL and GLUT freeze on Mac OS X? Can I use GLFW over GLUT?

Tags: macos, opengl, haskell, glut

I am trying to do graphics in Haskell and have been using Haskell.org's tutorial (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1). However, when I attempt to execute the following code (this code was taken DIRECTLY from the linked tutorial above):

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  flush
```

Everything successfully compiles but upon actually running the "main", a white, ghc window opens and immediately freezes. I have tried using other code from this tutorial but to no avail. I am running OS X 10.8.5 and using EclipseFP. Is this a MAC only problem?

Comment: Have you tried a simple OpenGL test written in C?

Comment: Is this happening in ghci or when running `ghc --make`?

Comment: I have written OpenGL in Java and that works fine. This happens in ghci, user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part of your question: There is an unresolved problem with GLFW (at least GLFW-b) on OS X with GHC 7.6.3. See this GitHub Issue:
https://github.com/bsl/bindings-GLFW/issues/8

Given the comments on that issue, it appears that the problem will be resolved once GHC 7.8 has been released.
Personally, I'm currently in the same boat as you, looking for ANY OpenGL Haskell binding that works under OS X!

Update: I've discovered that GLUT works for me if I compile first with `ghc`, and then run, rather than attempting to run via `ghci` or `runghc`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: `ghci` or `runhaskell` still doesn't work in 7.8, but compiling fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a MacBook? A quick hacky fix is to go to System Prefs / Energy Saver options and disable 'Automatic Graphics Switching'.

I don't know why this happens, but it's damn irritating. It doesn't happen for me with a C program, eg glxgears.

Comment: I am on a 13-inch MacBook Pro and do not have Automatic Graphics Switching. Is there another way to achieve the same effect? Thanks

Comment: Oh, I thought all MacBook Pros had the two graphics cards, but maybe it's only retina?
Maybe try running with `+RTS -V0`…

Comment: Only 15-inch MacBook Pro laptops have discrete graphics cards -- the 13-inch models only use Intel integrated graphics chipsets.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry then. I guess it's a different thing to what I have

Comment: @TrevorPowell do you know any fixes to this, Trevor? I looked briefly into GLFW but couldn't get that working either…Thanks everyone, all your help is much appreciated!

Comment: @user3175426 Sorry, I have no experience with Haskell programming, and the code you posted doesn't look like native OpenGL code, so I can't really use my OpenGL knowledge to provide advice.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Using GHC 7.4.2, installed cuboid in November 2013, only 3D Haskell application to work so far. Decided to play with the code today and found out both the old executable and the copy I made wouldn't swap render buffers without you resizing the window then minimizing it each time, nor would the Elerea examples. Those use GLFW and OpenGL, not GLUT.